# Natvis Error: this dynamic_cast cannot be done without runtime type information, which is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2015, rtti, natvis

I have a dynamic cast in a .natvis file, but when the object that contains that cast is looked at, I get the error message:

`Natvis Error: this dynamic_cast cannot be done without runtime type information, which is disabled`

I've went through every project in the solution and turned it on.  There are also a lot of `dynamic_cast` calls which do work as expected in the code prior to doing this so I don't know what is up with `natvis` complaining about this.

Does anyone know if doing dynamic_casts is allows in natvis?  Can't seem to find anything one way or the other on this.

Comment: I've added a bug report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3050623/watch-window-and-natvis-do-not-allow-dynamic-cast).  It says it is now closed as fixed, but I don't know when they may introduce this 'fix' to the general community.

Comment: If that was just a bug in VS you should write that as an answer (possibly with some more information about the VS versions affected) and accept it.